# Reading POST variables with ASPX vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, forms, post

I need to read variables from POST method in ASPX (VB version).

Here the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <script runat="server">
        Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
            Response.Write("[POST]<br />")
            For Each s As String In Request.Form.AllKeys
                Response.Write("[Request.Form] " & s & ": " & Request.Form(s) & "<br />")
            Next
            Response.Write("[GET] <br />")
            For Each a As String In Request.QueryString.AllKeys
                Response.Write("[Request.QueryString] " & a & ": " & Request(a) & "<br />")
            Next
        End Sub
</script>
<body>
<form action="demo_simpleform.aspx" method="post">
    <input name="infob" type="text" value="POST" id="infob" disabled />
    <input name="TextBox1" type="text" value="" id="TextBox1" />
    <input name="TextBox2" type="password" id="TextBox2" />
    <input type="submit" value="Method POST" />
</form>
<form action="demo_simpleform.aspx" method="get">
    <input name="infoa" type="text" value="GET" id="infoa" disabled />
    <input name="TextBox1a" type="text" value="" id="TextBox1a" />
    <input name="TextBox2a" type="password" id="TextBox2a"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Method GET"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Why I cannot read POST variables? What's wrong?
Help me, pls

Comment: What did you try? What do you mean "cannot"?

Answer (score 0):

I have found solutions (but I don't understand why ...)

I must transform FORM action="demo_simpleform.aspx" method="post" into FORM runat="server".
Ok, I understand that MUST insert runat="server" parameter (in form declaration and in all objects inside my form) but why I nedd to remove action="demo_simpleform.aspx" method="post" ?

Here the working code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <script runat="server">
        Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
            Response.Write("[POST]<br />")
            For Each s As String In Request.Form.AllKeys
                Response.Write("[Request.Form] " & s & ": " & Request.Form(s) & "<br />")
            Next
            Response.Write("[GET] <br />")
            For Each a As String In Request.QueryString.AllKeys
                Response.Write("[Request.QueryString] " & a & ": " & Request(a) & "<br />")
            Next
        End Sub
</script>
<body>
<form runat="server">
    <input runat="server" name="infob" type="text" value="POST 2" id="infob" disabled />
    <input runat="server" name="TextBox1" type="text" value="" id="TextBox1" />
    <input runat="server" name="TextBox2" type="password" id="TextBox2" />
    <input runat="server" type="submit" value="Method POST 2" />
</form>
<form action="demo_simpleform.aspx" method="get">
    <input name="infoa" type="text" value="GET" id="infoa" disabled />
    <input name="TextBox1a" type="text" value="" id="TextBox1a" />
    <input name="TextBox2a" type="password" id="TextBox2a"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Method GET"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```